# PdhGetFormattedCounterValue and correct Format

Tags: c++, winapi, performancecounter, pdh

Im trying to understand the performance API but I have a problem to understand the `PdhGetFormattedCounterValue` function and the `dwFormat` parameter.

How do I know which format to choose when calling this function?

I found the `PDH_COUNTER_INFO` structure on MSDN and saw that this structure has a `dwType` member but I still not understand how to use this structure to get information about the counter format to successfully call the `PdhGetFormattedCounterValue` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get to choose.

Many counters are calculated as fractions or they are scaled or both, so they have fractional parts.  Which makes `PDH_FMT_DOUBLE` a good choice.

Some counter types never have fractional parts.  You *could* read all the documentation and work out which, and then add two code paths to handle "counters that might be fractional" and "counters that won't be fractional", but this would be a lot of work for very little gain or none.

Just use `PDH_FMT_DOUBLE`.

**Update**

For most counters the precision is only a concern during the calculation of the final value, which happens within the PDH library.  But, as you say, the precision of bulk totals (such as disk free space) *could* be an issue.  Happily, it isn't.

A double has 52 bits of significand.  For a counter reported in bytes this has room for 4 petabytes without any loss of precision.

But disk free space is reported in megabytes, not bytes, so a double can report up to 2<sup>72</sup> bytes or 4 zettabytes with no loss of precision.  And I'm pretty sure you can't have a single volume bigger than 2<sup>64</sup> bytes.

Memory use (of processes and so) is reported in bytes but the values are always multiples of the page size (4096 bytes), so the bottom 12 bits of any reported value are zero.  Hence a double can represent a memory size of up to 2<sup>64</sup> bytes - i.e. the entire 64-bit memory space - without loss of precision.

Precision isn't a problem.  Just use `PDH_FMT_DOUBLE`.

Comment: Hi, I was thinking a bit about your comment and I think that I might get accuracy problems when using only doubles. On server systems with lots of RAM or with large HDDs this might get a problem.